# Who is the oldest ruler whose remains can be positively identified?

Tags: ancient-history, rulers

I realize this question can be quite controversial since "positive identification" is rather subjective especially with regards to ancient history. Regardless, I am curious to know which ancient rulers historians are fairly confident we can identify remains for.

My first guess would be one of the early Egyptian pharaohs, perhaps [Narmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narmer)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The oldest would appear to be the Old Kingdom pharaoh **[Neferefre](http://www.ancient-egypt-online.com/neferefre.html) (5th dynasty) who is estimated to have died around 2458 BC**. When found,

> The tomb was lined and sealed with pink granite. It contained parts of
> a pink sarcophagus, alabaster Canopic jars, alabaster offering
> containers and the remnants of a mummy. Upon investigation,
> archaeologists believe the mummy to be that of King Neferefre. He was
> probably between 20 to 23 years old at the time of death.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neferefre#Reign_duration), citing  Strouhal & Vyhnánek (2000), states Neferefre is "one of the very few Old Kingdom pharaohs whose mummy has been identified."

Next oldest ruler with identified remains is **[Djedkare Isesi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djedkare_Isesi#Pyramid), also of the 5th dynasty, who died around 2375 BC**. As with Neferefre, we can't be 100% sure about the identification: "the mummy [*currently thought*](http://ancientegyptonline.co.uk/djedkare.html) to be Djedkare's suggests he was about 50 when he died."

The oldest remains of a **ruler (positively identified) which are on display is the mummy [Seqenenre Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqenenre_Tao) (or Tao II)**, 14th Pharaoh of the [Theban dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_Dynasty_of_Egypt) (Egypt) during the [Second Intermediate period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Intermediate_Period_of_Egypt). We have some details of his [(gruesome) death](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1769615/), but the date is uncertain: he is believed to have started ruling around 1560 BC (or a bit later). [This source](http://www.nemo.nu/ibisportal/0egyptintro/6egypt/index.htm) gives the dates 1558 - 1554 BC.

[image: Seqenenre Tao]

*"[Mummified head of Seqenenre depicting his battlewounds](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sequenre_tao.JPG)" The mummy can be seen in the Egyptian Museum in Cairo.*

The mummy of one of Seqenenre's sons and successors, [Ahmose I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmose_I) (died about 1524 BC), has also been positively identified.

[image: Ahmose I mummy head]
[*The mummified head of Egyptian pharaoh King Ahmose I*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ahmose-mummy-head.png)

Also of interest, but a prince rather than a ruler, is [Ranefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranefer), son of the [4th dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Dynasty_of_Egypt) Pharaoh [Sneferu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneferu) (died around 2589 BC). Ranefer died before his father. Citing [Ikram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salima_Ikram) & Dodson, Wikipedia states "Ranefer’s body is the best representation of what mummification techniques entailed during the Old Kingdom."

Remains of rulers from other regions of the world are much more recent. **Among the oldest in Western Europe are those of the Merovingian [King Clovis I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clovis_I) (died 511 AD)** which were relocated from their original site to the [Basilica of St. Denis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_St_Denis). **In Latin America, a [discovery in Guatemala](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2017/09/ancient-maya-king-tomb-spd/) has been dated to 300 to 350 AD may be the remains of the Mayan ruler King Te’ Chan Ahk**, but this is just a 'best guess'. Worth a mention also is the Chinese noblewoman [Xin Zhui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xin_Zhui) (died 163 BC) whose mummy

> was remarkably preserved. Her skin was soft and moist, with muscles
> that still allowed for her arms and legs to flex at the joints. All
> her organs and blood vessels were also intact, with small amounts of
> Type A blood being found in her veins. There was hair on her head....There was skin on her face, and her eyelashes and nose hair still exist.

Answer (score 4):

http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/oldest-pharaoh-carvings_n_2271909.html

Narmer's tomb and remains have never been located.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneferu

http://dome.mit.edu/handle/1721.3/21094

The oldest known remains are of **Sneferu**, from about 2600 BC.

The unknown royals in the royal tombs at Ur are not far ahead, dating around 2500 BC.

http://mcclungmuseum.utk.edu/exhibits/tombs-of-ur/

Comment: From the Wikipedia article you linked to:
"Considering that the remains of King Sneferu have not yet been found, it still may be possible that his sarcophagus and mummy lie hidden in his mysterious last structure."

Comment: @terminex9. You asked about "positive identification", not "still may be possible".